# Controlling variables for different kind of measures

Tags: multiple-regression, continuous-data, discrete-data, categorical-data

I would like to test group differences for further measures controlling for other variables.

However, the measures are from different types :
- continuous variables
- discrete positive variables (some with a lot of zeros)
- dichotomous variables
- nominal variables

For continuous variables, it is easy, I use linear regression analysis. As for dichotomous variables, I use logistic regression. But for others?
For discrete positive variables, do I use Poisson regression models (and zero-inflated models for measures with a lot of zeros)?
For nominal variables, do I use multinomial logistic regression?
Or is there something I don't understand in controlling variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model type you specify only depends on your output variable/outcome that you're modeling. So, if your outcome is continuous, then use linear regression but if it's not continuous you have to use something else.

In general, if your inputs are discrete you have to use some binary encoding to properly capture their representation.

As a concrete example, consider the following model:

Output:

- Income (continuous)

Inputs:

- Age (continuous)
- Degree Attained (categorical - discrete)
- Gender (dichotomous - discrete)
- Number of children (nominal - discrete)

This is what your matrix should look like.

```
Age | Degree_HighSchool | Degree_College | Degree_None | Gender_Male | Gender_Female | NChildren_1 | NChildren_2| ... | NChildren_n
23  | 1                 | 0              | 0           | 1           | 0             | 1           | 0          | ... | 0
```

The number of children is actually a little more complicated because with sufficient range and density, it can be approximated by treating it as a continuous input. In general though, for inputs with few distinct values and that are nominal it's better to use the binary representation.

The coefficients that you ultimately learn from these binary encodings is a single coefficient for each group, which makes sense because from their you can see what function is being learned.

Hope that helps.

Edit

Here's the list when you're referring to those 4 as your outputs.

- Different continuous variables

  - [0, $\infty$) = Log-Normal, Gamma, Gompertz, Weibull and others
  - [0, 1] = Beta regression
- discrete positive variables (some with a lot of zeros)

  - [0, $n$) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ = Poisson regression (or Negative-Binomial)
  - [0, $n$) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ = Zero-inflated Poisson or Tweedie
- Dichotomous variables

  - {0, 1}, Bernoulli
- Categorical variables

  - {0, 1, 2, .., K}, Multinomial Logistic
- Nominal variables

  - {0< 1< 2< ...< K}, Ordered Probit/Logistic

It's worth noting that there are many variants on this and you can even do mixture of these and make much more complicated distributions.

Comment: I may have misspoke myself. My question is about which kind of models should I use knowing that I am interested in 4 kind of outputs? I have continuous outputs (ok I will use linear regression), dichotomous outputs (ok I will use logistic regression), discrete outputs and nominal outputs. This study is performed to test group differences with controlling for others variables.

Comment: I've updated my response.